# get the keyset of a nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap with nested hashmaps.

```
    private Map<LocalDate, HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Pair<Long, Long>, String>>> campusDatabase = new HashMap<>();
```

so I want to get a list of the Integers in the nested hashmap.

```
        ArrayList<Integer> roomNumbers = this.campusDatabase.values().stream().flatMap(h -> h.keySet().stream()).collect(ArrayList::new);
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            List<Integer> roomNumbers = campusDatabase.values().stream()
            .flatMap(h -> h.keySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I really need to understand why that would work for lists, but not arraylists.